# Java out of memory exception when running as a non root user

Tags: memory, java

I'm attempting to run apache kafka on a small basically stock digital ocean server running centos 6.6. I'm not positive if this issue is kafka specific or not. When I run kafka as the root user everything behaves fine. However when I attempt to run as a non root user that I created called kafka, I consistently get a java out of memory exception on startup that looks like this

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c5330000, 986513408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

What would cause this behavior and how can I ensure this process runs under the non root user account?

The machine has 1GB total memory and 1GB swap. The kafka user was created as a system user, if that's at all relevant.

As far as I can tell there are no ulimits that would be relevant to this issue

**Update**

I was able to get it working by adding `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS='-Xmx256M -Xms128M` at the front of the command, but it's still not clear why the non-root user has access to less memory than the root user.

Comment: When you run 'ulimit -v' as the new user you created, do you get "unlimited" as response?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I get.

Comment: Try disabling the large page use by adding "-XX:-UseLargePages" to the JVM options.